# Understanding how CString.Format works

Tags: c++, mfc, format, c-strings

At work, we have a problem understanding how the CString.Format-Method actually works.

I am working on an existing project, that includes a password-hasher. The part I don't understand is the  Format-Method. For example, if you type in "password", then another method makes 89.498161499544608 out of it. I get the part where this happens, and only the double is necessary now.

```
CString str;
str.Format(_T("%x"), 89.498161499544608);
```

I replaced variable names with the actual value I work with. In this case, str becomes "e0c52ae8". I played around a bit with the method.
If I format with `15.000000000000020`, the result will be "b", but when using `0.000000000000020`, the result is "86a12b9b". The part I don't get is, that if the number before the comma is not 15, then my theory `Every second number adds one to the Hex-code` is wrong. When 15, then `15.000...0001` is 1, `15.000...0003` is 2 etc, but when 0, the results are "9ee75616" for `0.00...0001` and 
"6e5b0120" for `0.00...0003`

Comment: The value `89.498161499544608` is a floating-point value of type `double`. The format `"%x"` is to print integers of type `unsigned int`. Those two types are not stored in memory in a compatible manner. `Format` and the related `printf` functions are not type-safe in any way, and there's no conversion between types in the argument lists.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but that won't answer the question, how Format() makes "6e5b0120" out of ``0.00...0003`` or "9ee75616" out of ``0.00...0001``

Comment: Probably because that's the binary contents (presented as hexadecimal) of the lower (or higher) 32 bits of the `double` value? Floating point values just aren't stored the same way as integers, they are most likely stored using an [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) format.

Comment: FYI Formatting with `CString::Format` works exactly the same way as formatting in `printf` does

Comment: This is invoking *undefined behavior*. Interpreting a type as if it were a different, unrelated type has no well-defined meaning. Whatever happens, happens. It's entirely not interesting to figure out, what any given implementation does, when confronted with a construct that exhibits UB. Just fix your code, either by supplying a compatible type specifier, or by supplying a compatible type.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but password hashing should be done properly, what you're trying to do here looks phishy anyway from the cryptographic point of view. Google is your friend.

Comment: Despite the code looks as it does, the main question was, how Format() works as it does. What makes Format() return "9ee75616" when using 0.000...003 as parameter? What's the algorithm that calculates this string?

Comment: There is no deterministic algorithm involved. The behavior is undefined. Your format string promises, that you are passing an integer, but you are passing a floating point value. All bets are off at that point. Depending on the architecture and platform you are using, the `printf` implementation may be looking in the wrong place altogether (general purpose registers vs. FPU/SSE registers). The question is truly meaningless, and an answer is likely not going to be useful. Don't lie to the compiler or the compiler will punish you, with extreme prejudice.